# ActiveMQ forwarding bridge with failover

Tags: activemq-classic, mom

Here is what I try to achieve with ActiveMQ:
I'd like to have 2 clusters of brokers: clusterA and clusterB. Data between these 2 clusters should be mirrored. So, when clusterA receives a message it will be stored at storageA and also this message should be forwarded to clusterB (if there is such demand) and stored in storageB. On the other hand if clusterB receives a message it should be forwarded to clusterA.
I'm wondering whether config like this considered to be valid according to described above:

```
    <networkConnectors>
    <networkConnector 
          uri="static:(failover(tcp://clusterB_broker1:port,tcp://clusterB_broker2:port,tcp://clusterB_broker3:port))"
          name="bridge"
          duplex="true"
          conduitSubscriptions="true"
          decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="false"/> 
    </networkConnectors>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *valid* configuration.  It indicates (assuming that all ClusterA brokers are configured this way) that brokers in ClusterA will store and forward first to `clusterB_broker1`, and if it is down will instead store and forward to `clusterB_broker2`, and then to `clusterB_broker3` if `clusterB_broker2` is down.  But depending on your intra-cluster broker configuration, it is not going to do what you want it to.

The broker configurations **must** be set up for failover themselves or else you will lose messages when `clusterB_broker1` goes down.  If clusterB brokers are not working together as described below, then when `clusterB_broker1` goes down, any messages sent to it will not be present or accessible on the other clusterB brokers.  New messages will forward to them.

How to do failover within the cluster depends on your ActiveMQ version.

The latest version (5.9.0) [supports](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html) 3 failover (or master/slave) cluster configurations.  For quick reference, they are:

- Shared File System Master Slave
- JDBC Master Slave
- Replicated LevelDB Store

Earlier versions supported a master/slave configuration that had one master and one slave node where messages were forwarded to the slave broker.  This setup was not well maintained, had bugs, and has been removed from ActiveMQ.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do not quite understand, are you talking about data replication or failover of the brokers that form a cluster?

Comment: i updated my answer.  let me know if that is clearer.